# How to store images in a directory in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to store multiple images whenever a user clicks on a button. Right now I have

```
#Define path to store the images

image.out.path <- "/data/documents/images/diedata/testimage.png"
image.connection <- file(image.out.path, open="wb", raw=TRUE)
#create an image, where input.image is an input parameter that takes a photo
writeBin(input.image, image.connection)
```

Current code only stores one image and if the user clicks on a button it will replace the image in testimage.png. Rather then replacing, how can i add further images into the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural thing is to maintain a counter variable, say `image_count`, which is initially set to 1 and then replace the line

```
image.out.path <- "/data/documents/images/diedata/testimage.png"
```

by the two lines

```
image.out.path <- paste0("/data/documents/images/diedata/testimage",image_count,".png")
image_count <- image_count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be some ways

1) generate RND add to file name

```
image.out.path <- paste0("/data/documents/images/diedata/testimage_",runif(1),".png")
```

But it s not 100% good way

2) Add time to file name

```
image.out.path <- paste0("/data/documents/images/diedata/testimage_",Sys.time(),".png")
```

But only one file in sec.

3) Choose files in dir and if already exist add index

Its will be work only if you have right filename format

```
all_files=list.files(pattern = "test")
max_ind=as.numeric(substring(all_files,gregexpr("_",all_files)[[1]]+1,gregexpr("\\.",all_files)[[1]]-1))
max_ind=max_ind+1
image.out.path <- paste0("test_",max_ind,".png")
```

if you create all files in one session you can simply `max_ind=max_ind+1` each button click